# Add border and change color dynamically to PointSeries in Lightning chart

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I use below code

```
const pointz = chart.addPointSeries({ pointShape: PointShape.Circle })
    .setName('Kuopio')
    .setPointFillStyle(fillStyles[0])
    .setPointSize(pointSize)
    .setMaxPointCount(10000);
```

To create some point chart like below

[image]

Is there any way I can add border color to this circles ? And also How to change individual color seperately Thank you.

I tried  , but its not changing the color

```
 pointz.add({ x: xVal, y: yVal-20, color: ColorRGBA( 255, 255, 255 )})
```

Please use this like jsfiddle - https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0006-pointClusters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PointSeries in LightningChart JS doesn't support adding a border to the points.

To change the point colors individually, you need to use [IndividualPointFill](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.0/classes/individualpointfill.html).
When you create a new IndividualPointFill, you need to specify a fallback color. This color is used when the point doesn't have other color information associated with it.

```js
const fillStyle = new IndividualPointFill({ color: ColorHSV(0) })

const series = chart.addPointSeries()
    .setPointFillStyle(fillStyle)

// add a point using the fallback color
series.add({x: 0, y: 0})

// add a point and specify the color
series.add({x: 1, y: 0, color: ColorHSV(200)})
```

```js
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
    lightningChart,
    SolidFill,
    SolidLine,
    ColorPalettes,
    emptyFill,
    AxisTickStrategies,
    PointShape,
    IndividualPointFill,
    ColorHSV
} = lcjs

// ----- Cache used styles -----
const pointSize = 10
const palette = ColorPalettes.fullSpectrum(10)
const colors = [0, 6].map(palette)
const fillStyles = colors.map(color => new IndividualPointFill({ color }))
// Decide on an origin for DateTime axis.
const dateOrigin = new Date(2018, 8, 1)

// Create a XY Chart.
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    defaultAxisXTickStrategy: AxisTickStrategies.DateTime(dateOrigin),
})
    .setPadding({
        right: 50
    })

// Add a series for each cluster of points
const fstClusterSeries = chart.addPointSeries({ pointShape: PointShape.Circle })
    .setPointFillStyle(fillStyles[0])
    .setPointSize(pointSize)
const sndClusterSeries = chart.addPointSeries({ pointShape: PointShape.Triangle })
    .setPointFillStyle(fillStyles[1])
    .setPointSize(pointSize)

// The point supplied to series will have their X values multiplied by this value (for easier addition of DateTime-values).
const dataFrequency = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
const kuopioPoints = [
    { x: 12.152641878669275, y: 5335.336538461539 },
    { x: 11.62426614481409, y: 5259.615384615385 },
    { x: 10.919765166340508, y: 5082.932692307692 },
    { x: 10.156555772994128, y: 4923.076923076923 },
    { x: 9.334637964774949, y: 4796.875 },
    { x: 8.101761252446183, y: 4704.326923076923 },
    { x: 6.634050880626223, y: 4620.192307692308 },
    { x: 3.933463796477495, y: 4418.2692307692305 },
    { x: 3.111545988258317, y: 4342.548076923077 },
    { x: 2.8180039138943247, y: 4199.5192307692305 },
    { x: 2.8180039138943247, y: 4014.423076923077 },
    { x: 2.4657534246575334, y: 3930.2884615384614 },
    { x: 2.407045009784736, y: 3745.1923076923076 },
    { x: 2.935420743639921, y: 3408.653846153846 },
    { x: 3.6399217221135025, y: 3307.6923076923076 },
    { x: 5.107632093933463, y: 3181.4903846153848 },
    { x: 6.868884540117416, y: 3181.4903846153848 },
    { x: 7.749510763209393, y: 3198.3173076923076 },
    { x: 9.217221135029353, y: 3316.1057692307695 },
    { x: 10.215264187866929, y: 3475.9615384615386 },
    { x: 11.037181996086105, y: 3585.3365384615386 },
    { x: 12.035225048923678, y: 3719.951923076923 },
    { x: 12.798434442270057, y: 3778.846153846154 },
    { x: 16.027397260273972, y: 3820.9134615384614 },
    { x: 22.544031311154598, y: 3896.6346153846152 },
    { x: 24.187866927592953, y: 3963.9423076923076 }
]

const helsinkiPoints = [
    { x: 6.164383561643835, y: 2314.6634615384614 },
    { x: 6.516634050880624, y: 2351.2019230769233 },
    { x: 7.045009784735812, y: 2479.0865384615386 },
    { x: 7.279843444227005, y: 2543.028846153846 },
    { x: 7.514677103718199, y: 2638.9423076923076 },
    { x: 8.277886497064578, y: 2794.230769230769 },
    { x: 8.63013698630137, y: 2853.605769230769 },
    { x: 10.156555772994128, y: 2972.355769230769 },
    { x: 10.919765166340508, y: 3018.028846153846 },
    { x: 11.800391389432484, y: 3063.7019230769233 },
    { x: 12.798434442270057, y: 3109.375 },
    { x: 14.442270058708415, y: 3155.0480769230767 },
    { x: 16.320939334637963, y: 2538.4615384615386 },
    { x: 17.729941291585128, y: 2511.0576923076924 },
    { x: 14.442270058708415, y: 2465.3846153846152 },
    { x: 12.093933463796477, y: 2529.326923076923 },
    { x: 12.857142857142856, y: 2597.8365384615386 },
    { x: 12.563600782778865, y: 2419.7115384615386 },
    { x: 12.798434442270057, y: 2342.0673076923076 },
    { x: 13.79647749510763, y: 2296.394230769231 },
    { x: 13.033268101761252, y: 2282.6923076923076 },
]

// Setup view nicely.
chart.getDefaultAxisX()
    .setInterval(0 * dataFrequency, 30 * dataFrequency, true, true)

chart.getDefaultAxisY()
    .setInterval(1500, 6500, true, true)
/**
* Adds clusters of points to specified series and creates frames for them
* @param {PointSeries} series Series which should hold the cluster
* @return Function which receives a cluster of points
*/
const drawCluster = (series, points, colorOffset) => {
    // Add points to specified series
    series.add(points.map(point => ({
        x: point.x * dataFrequency,
        y: point.y,
        color: Math.random() > 0.5 ? ColorHSV(colorOffset + (50 * Math.random())) : undefined
    })))
}

drawCluster(fstClusterSeries, kuopioPoints, 100)
drawCluster(sndClusterSeries, helsinkiPoints, 0)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi , How does this have border - https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0705-customChartBubbles.html

Comment: That example is using EllipseSeries to display the circles. It's a lot more manual and flexible method to show ellipses. It could be used like point series, expect it will not scale the ellipses when the chart is zoomed, unless the series is attached to axis that is using ui scale as the scale. EllipseSeries does support stroke style and thus having border. It requires the styles to be set to each ellipse separately. If you really want to have borders I would add another PointSeries under the actual point series and have the point size a bit larger. Only do this if you dont have a lot of data.

Comment: We have considered adding a possibility to add a border to the PointSeries points. I can't promise a timeline for when it would be done, but it's being planned to be added in a future release. (I'm the lead architect for LightningChart JS)

Comment: Ah thank you so much , Also is there any way I can use PAN and drag the chart around , right now its creating rectangle...

Comment: I have mac , how do I pan ? even right click is drawing rectangle

Comment: Using two fingers to click and drag should do a right click on mac. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207700 I have tested and confirmed that it does work.

Comment: Two fingers click and drag is zooming in and out.